# Trigger the controller to display view

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a dropdown in view that is using js I pass the selected item from dropdown to controller, inside the controller I ran a query using the selected item from dropdown to extract some records. Now the problem is that I cannot display the query result to view. Basically I cannot trigger the controller to display in view.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the js to pass the data to controller:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function(){
    $('.defined_call').bind('change', function(){
        alert($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            url: "<%= changeowner_path %>",
            data: { my_str: $(this).val() }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<%= select_tag "dropdown_cases", options_for_select(@ownerlist),{:id=>"defined_Id",:class 
=> "defined_call'}  %>
```

Here is the controller:

```
class ReassignsController < ApplicationController
  def changeowner
    i=0
    $myarr=[]
    ownerl = Transaction.owner#declaredin model
    @ownerlist=ownerl.collect { |c| [ c, c ] }#make it for dropdown
    value=params[:my_str]#return value from dropdown
    $value1=value.to_s#make it for owner table
    @owner_records=Transaction.where(:owner => $value1) 

    ===> I would like to display to the view?
  end
end
```

Here is the view that I am using:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="sortTableExample">
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center">Book Name</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Owner</th>

</tr>

<% @owner_records.each do |arr_data| %>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center"><%= arr_data.book%></td>
<td style="text-align:center"><%= arr_data.owner%></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe, Try something like:

```
  $('.defined_call').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<%= changeowner_path %>", type: 'get', 
            data: { my_str: $(this).val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
              if (data == "") {
                alert('No Results');
              }
              else {
                var jsonObj = eval( data );
                var count = jsonObj.transactions.length;
                for (var i = 0; i<count; i=i+1) {
                  $('#sortTableExample').append('<td style="text-align:center">' + jsonObj.transactions[i].book + '</td><td style="text-align:center">' + jsonObj.transactions[i].owner + '</td>');
                }
              }
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: thank you. Basically what I am trying to do is as follows:

1.Pass the selected item from view’s dropdown to controller
2.Inside controller run a query and use the selected item from (dropdown) inside the Where condition
3.Pass the query result to a table inside view (same view as step 1) for display

My posted solution does cover step 1 and step 2 but I missing step 3 to populate the table’s view. How do I trigger the display table using you solution?

Comment: Hey Joe, this step is the one that should change the table. Have you got your project on github.. I can try to have a look at it for you.                  $('#sortTableExample').append('<td style="text-align:center">' + jsonObj.transactions[i].book + '</td><td style="text-align:center">' + jsonObj.transactions[i].owner + '</td>');

Comment: Joe, try putting alert(jsonObj.transactions[i].book); and see if the code is working. If it is, then we can help you with your table update.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked, the only minor change I made was that I retrieve the data from controller using JSON.stringify(data) instead of using  jsonObj = eval( data ).

Answer (score 0):

Rails is rendering your view, you just aren't doing anything with it on the client side (in javascript).

In your ajax call you want to do something on success:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "<%= changeowner_path %>",
   data: { my_str: $(this).val() },
   success: function(data) {
       $('#myDiv').html(data); // This is writing the returned view from rails to myDiv
   }
});
```